# What does an unspecified unconverted data mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I am trying to use `strptime` to format a time string that I have, but it gives the error of

> "ValueError: unconverted data remains:" 
>   without actually specifying what data it's missing

I'm not quite sure how to fix this problem. Here is what I've tried :

```
t = 'Tue, 26 Mar 2019 06:25:01 GMT'
def function(t):
    timeString = t 
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeString, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%s %Z')
```

I think maybe the issue is something to do with the floating point that's supposed to be there at the end. Any help would be appreciated. Also, any tips to convert this to another time zone would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) library to parse datetime string.

Here is an example:

```
from dateutil import parser 
datetime_string = 'Tue, 26 Mar 2019 06:25:01 GMT'
dt = parser.parse(datetime_string)
print(dt)
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 26, 6, 25, 1, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score -1):

> "ValueError: unconverted data remains:"

This indicates that datetime was unable to convert the data you supplied, probably due to a format error as it tried to parse an unexpected value.

Turns out that is the case, you have a typo. Change the **s** in the time format to capital **S**

```
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeString, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```